# Trying to set all nodes checked status in a treeview - get StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have some nodes added to my `TreeView` (trvP). The root element has `Tag` property set to `Root`.

I'm trying to make it so if I check the root element, all other nodes will have the same status. However, executing the code below results in `StackOverflowException`.

```
private void trvP_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
        if(e.Node.Tag.Equals("Root"))
        {
            var nodes = TreeViewExtensions.GetAllNodes(e.Node.TreeView);
            foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
                node.Checked = e.Node.Checked;
        }
}
```

The code for `GetAllNodes` function:

```
public static List<TreeNode> GetAllNodes(this TreeView _trv)
{
        List<TreeNode> result = new List<TreeNode>();
        foreach (TreeNode child in _trv.Nodes)
        {
            result.AddRange(child.GetAllNodes());
        }
        return result;
}
public static List<TreeNode> GetAllNodes(this TreeNode _trn)
    {
        List<TreeNode> result = new List<TreeNode>();
        result.Add(_trn);
        foreach (TreeNode child in _trn.Nodes)
        {
            result.AddRange(child.GetAllNodes());
        }
        return result;
    }
```

It seems from debugging that it runs the `var nodes = ...` piece of code over and over, while only setting single node inside the `foreach` loop (the root node). However, `nodes` is a proper list of nodes with right values.

I can't see why this is executing over and over resulting in an exception.

Comment: Can you show the `GetAllNodes()` extension for `TreeNode` (you only show the one for `TreeView`)?

Comment: And I guess the root node will be the first in your list, so `node.Checked = ...` will call the handler `trvP_AfterCheck()` again for the same node (though this should not happen if the checkstate did not change).

Comment: Added, but as said below, `GetAllNodes` works fine if I call it for some random child element (which also has children) - it's only the root element causing problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GetAllNodes()` extension for a `TreeView` starts with the first child node and calls the `GetAllNodes()` extension for this `TreeNode`.

This `GetAllNodes()` extension adds this very `TreeNode` to the result list.
So the **first** `TreeNode` in your list is your **root node again**.

This means in the line

```
node.Checked = e.Node.Checked;
```

you set the `Checked` property of your **root node**, which in turn calls the handler `trvP_AfterCheck` *again for this root node*. This now repeats infinitly, flooding your stack and raising the `StackOverflowException`.

To solve this, filter out the root node:

```
private void trvP_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
        if(e.Node.Tag.Equals("Root"))
        {
            var nodes = e.Node.TreeView.GetAllNodes();
            foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
            {
                if (node == e.Node) continue; // don't do it for root again
                node.Checked = e.Node.Checked;
            }
        }
}
```

---

Btw: the nice thing about extension methods is that you can call them syntactically as if they were instanc methods. So this

```
var nodes = TreeViewExtensions.GetAllNodes(e.Node.TreeView)
```

can simply be written as

```
var nodes = e.Node.TreeView.GetAllNodes();
```

Comment: I didn't consider that a complete list would raise the event over and over, this is a great explanation, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you are calling GetAllNodes recursively which makes loop into infinite state..

try

```
    public static List<TreeNode> GetAllNodes(this TreeView _trv)
{
        List<TreeNode> result = new List<TreeNode>();
        foreach (TreeNode child in _trv.Nodes)
        {
            result.Add(child);
        }
        return result;
}
```

when you are already looping to treenode into _trv.Nodes, you jst need to add current node into foreach statement..

Comment: No, that misses the child nodes. Calling recursivly seems correct in OP's code as the recursion stops when there are no child nodes below.

Comment: GetAllNodes works fine, when I use it with some other `Tag` it works as expected, only when trying to work on `Root` element does it throw an exception.

Comment: @RenéVogt agree, I thought he need to traverse only through node parents sorry for miss.